# Could someone help to understand this batch script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm reading a batch file, but I do not understand it, can someone help to explain?

As I understand %0 is is the name of batch file, can we iterate on it? or is it a convenient way to represent a folder?

I can not find the variable %BatchPath% in the file, where do you think it's defined?
And it seems APATH is defined in the two loops?

```
for %%x in (%0) do set APATH=%%~dpsx
for %%x in (%BatchPath%) do set APATH=%%~dpsx
pushd %APATH%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over a single value. It just means the `set` statement is executed once. The `~dps` then strips the file name, so that only the directory remains.

The first line performs this action on %0, indeed the path and name of the current script.

The second line performs the same action on a given variable, Now that is the fun part, because if `%BatchPath%` is empty, nothing gets iterated, so the `set` statement on that line is not executed at all.

So effectively, it stores a directory, which is the directory of the script by default, but can be overridden by explicitly assigning a path to `%BatchPath%` before calling this script.

`pushd` allows you to save a directory, so you can return to it later using `popd`. It allows the script to jump to another directory an be able to restore the shell to the original directory before it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

> > %0 is the current batch file.
> >      %%~dpsx gives the current batch file's
> >     short path here its giving the Drive name for eg "D:\"
> >     **Pushd** Stores the name of the current directory for use by the popd command before changing the current directory to the specified
> >     directory.
> >     APATH is some variable used to store the path.

so basically the script is fetching details about the script file name , its drive location and storing it to be used as location from which last batch file ran or something like that.